# Enqueue scripts inside a class in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I have a plugin like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyPlugin
*/

class MyPlugin
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueueAssets'));
  }

  public function enqueueAssets()
  {
    wp_register_script('myplugin', plugins_url('myplugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('myplugin');
  }

  // More methods
}
```

The in a sidebar I create a new instance:

```
$plugin = new MyPlugin;
```

But when I open devtools in Chrome and go to "Sources" the assets are not being loaded. If I use a function *outside* the class it works:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueAssets');
function enqueueAssets()
{
  wp_register_script('myplugin', plugins_url('myplugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script('myplugin');
}

class MyPlugin
{
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I found out that if I instantiate the class inside the plugin it works, but I don't want to do this, I want the class to be instantiated in the sidebar. I could do both but that seems unnecesary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time your widget (or sidebar if this is hard-coded) loads you have already missed the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, which runs in the header and that means that you have missed the window for registering the script in the `<head>` at all, which you are trying to do-- there is no fifth parameter that would load the script in the footer.

You can enqueue in `wp_footer` or any other hook that runs after `wp_enqueue_scripts` so long as you add the fifth parameter so that the script loads in the footer.

```
class MyPlugin
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'enqueueAssets'));
  }

  public function enqueueAssets()
  {
    wp_register_script('myplugin', plugins_url('myplugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('myplugin');
  }

  // More methods
}
```

While the Codex does state that you should register on `wp_enqueue_scripts`, it also says:

> As of Version 3.3, the function can be called mid-page (before the
>   wp_footer() template tag) or using the wp_head action hook. This will
>   place the script in the footer as if the $in_footer parameter was set
>   to true.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script